# Starting remote workloads across platforms

Tags: linux, windows, automation, remote, aix

I work with a group that does integration testing for a IP/IPv6 network stack. We have many stress testing workloads that we run across a variety of platforms, including Linux (RHEL and SuSE), Windows (XP-2008), and a number of versions of AIX.

As of right now, our method for starting workloads across platforms involves us kicking off a dozen or more jobs manually across our test systems, however we're getting to the point where this is no longer feasible.

What sort of solutions exist for starting/stopping/querying workloads across multiple platforms and managing them at some higher level?

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://hudson-ci.org/

You can use it to run arbitrary tasks, not just building of java code.  It works better if your tests can generate output in the xunit xml format, but that isn't required.  It makes it easy to define sets of machines (32bit,64bit) (windows,linux) and run tests across different combinations.

Answer (score 1):

Hand around some ssh keys and launch from a shell script on one of the boxes?  There are ssh servers for Windows that should let you do this, and the unixen are no problem.